# MongoDB PHP driver can't installed Centos 6 cloud server

Tags: php, mongodb, centos, driver, centos6

I have installed MongoDB service in my Centos 6 cloud server. Now i need to install in my server php-pecl-mongo-1.2.10-1.el6.remi.x86_64.rpm... but it gives "packages not found". Can anyone fix this problem? My php version is PHP 5.3.3.

I am using putty for configuring Centos 6 server. I have admin privilege to configure php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- try RPM installing php-pecl-mongo without a specific version
- point to a specific RPM url for installation, eg. using  [rpmfind.net => php-pecl-mongo](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=php-pecl-mongo%5d)
- install using `sudo pecl install mongo` per the [Unix installation instructions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.nix)