# make fails trying to install mongo php driver on Centos 6

Tags: php, mongodb, centos6.5

I've tried two different ways to install the mongodb php driver.

- Compiling it based on directions from
  http://andres.jaimes.net/876/setup-mongo-php-module-centos-6/
- Issuing (as root) pecl install mongo

The server is Centos 6.6 (32-bit) that was originally a 6.5 virtualbox image that (following an update) now calls itself 6.6

The error seems to start here:

```
In file included from /var/tmp/mongo/io_stream.c:34:
/var/tmp/mongo/contrib/php-ssl.h:33:25: error: openssl/evp.h: No such file or directory
/var/tmp/mongo/contrib/php-ssl.h:34:26: error: openssl/x509.h: No such file or directory
/var/tmp/mongo/contrib/php-ssl.h:35:28: error: openssl/x509v3.h: No such file or directory
In file included from /var/tmp/mongo/io_stream.c:34:
/var/tmp/mongo/contrib/php-ssl.h:38: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/var/tmp/mongo/contrib/php-ssl.h:39: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/var/tmp/mongo/contrib/php-ssl.h:40: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
/var/tmp/mongo/io_stream.c: In function ‘php_mongo_io_stream_connect’:
/var/tmp/mongo/io_stream.c:189: error: ‘X509’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/var/tmp/mongo/io_stream.c:189: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/var/tmp/mongo/io_stream.c:189: error: for each function it appears in.)
/var/tmp/mongo/io_stream.c:189: error: ‘cert’ undeclared (first use in this function)
/var/tmp/mongo/io_stream.c:194: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
make: *** [io_stream.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

-other items of note:

```
php -v
PHP 5.6.6 (cli) (built: Feb 19 2015 10:19:59)
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies

mongo --version
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.8
openssl is installed 1.0.1e-30.e16_6_6.5.i686
```

I've checked other (seemingly related) Stack posts, such as [MongoDB PHP driver can't installed Centos 6 cloud server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11771429/mongodb-php-driver-cant-installed-centos-6-cloud-server) - but it didn't seem to help or apply.
Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Looks like you don't have the headers installed for OpenSSL.

Try `yum install openssl-devel` (or use sudo if not root) then recompile.

Comment: thanks that did the trick. I did not have openssl-devel installed. Afterwards... I got this, Build process completed successfully
    Installing '/usr/lib/php/modules/mongo.so'  You should add "extension=mongo.so" to php.ini 
    ...Of course line breaks don't show up in comments. But yes, it did install the driver and place it in the proper directory. Cheers!

Comment: It didn't solve my problem, All the packages in this response and the other responses are installed, any idea?

Comment: I have installed cyrus-sasl-devel and it resolves the error. I used this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26328099/559720

Answer (score 2):

For anyone the  command **yum install openssl-devel** did not solve Installing PHP56 Mongo Driver in  centos instance try to use/install these first

```
sudo yum install php-pear

sudo yum install php56-devel

sudo yum install gcc

sudo yum install openssl-devel

sudo pecl install mongodb
```